# Enforce specific MongoDB schema with node.js driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

How do I make MongoDB itself or some node.js driver for MongoDB require my documents to be a subset of a certain predefined schema.  I've heard it's possible, but I'm so far not finding exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that [mongoose.js](http://mongoosejs.com/) allows you to define a schema.
For example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var blogSchema = new Schema({
  title:  String,
  author: String,
  body:   String,
  comments: [{ body: String, date: Date }],
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  hidden: Boolean,
  meta: {
    votes: Number,
    favs:  Number
  }
});
```

With that you can define the schema of your collection.